# When to use trigger_error() vs throw new Error()?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, php-7

I `throw new Exception` when I can `catch` a failure and do something about it. If I can't do something about it then I just `trigger_error()`.

Now there's something new to me in PHP 7: `throw new Error`.

E.g.,

```
if (!mail(...))
    throw new Error('...');
```

or

```
if (!mail(...))
    trigger_error('...');
```

If I don't want to `catch` the error or do something in case `mail()` fails should I use `throw new Error()` or just the plain old `trigger_error()`?

What instances should we use `throw new Error()` vs a simple `trigger_error()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\Error` class was, as you already mentioned, introduced in PHP 7.

It acts exactly like an exception since it implements [`Throwable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php).

It's also subclasses by the following:

```
  ArithmeticError
    DivisionByZeroError
  AssertionError
  ParseError
  TypeError
    ArgumentCountError
```

However, it does not behave like `trigger_error()`, in fact it behaves exactly like an exception(mostly because it is one).

If you `trigger_error()` you can't catch it, because it's not an exception. Although there [are workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425835/converting-errors-to-exceptions-design-flaw).

---

This is mostly guestimating on my part.

I assume this exists for a more clear separation of Errors and Exceptions, possibly future plans include deprecating `trigger_error` and leaving just `Error`.

---

To answer your question.

I'd stick to `throwing` stuff rather than `trigger_error`. It's catchable, it's OOP.